# Fixing vulnerabilities in metasploitable 2

Tags: linux, penetration-test, metasploit, kali-linux, metasploitable

I am new to penetration testing .
I've done exploits from kali linux on metasploitable 2, and i want to fix the vulnerabilities i'm exploiting, but all i can find as a solution to these vulnerabilities is using firewalls or filtering ports. I thought about closing ports but i read it isn't possible without killing processes.
How should i fix vulnerabilities ?

Comment: What specific vulnerabilities are you trying to fix? What have you tried already?

Comment: @iain i exploited the VSFTPD backdoor vulnerability , the unreal IRCD vulnerability and the php cgi arg injection. And i want to fix these

Comment: You will get a better response if you post these as individual questions, you may want to share what have already tried to fix these specific vulnerabilities. You can also search this stack exchange for those vulnerabilities and see if anyone has already solved the problems you face.